# Tic-tac-toe using classes, compute victory condition

Tags: c++, class

I was trying to make a program for Tic-tac-toe between 2 players, using a class. But my `is_victory` function is always returning false. Why so?

```
//header file : tic_tac_toe.h
class Game
{
    public :
    Game();
    void insert(int , char);
    void print() const;
    bool is_empty(int) const;
    bool is_victory() const;
   
   
    private :
    char *pntr;
};
```

codefile:

```
// codefile for the class tic_tac_toe.cpp
#include"tic_tac_toe.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

Game::Game()
{
    pntr = new char[9] ;

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        pntr[i] = 48+i;
    }
}

void Game::insert(int location, char val)
{
    pntr[location] = val;
}

void Game::print() const
{
    for(int i=1; i<=9; i++)
    {
        cout<<pntr[i-1]<<"|";
        if(i%3 == 0) cout<<endl;
    }
}

bool Game::is_empty(int location) const
{
    if(pntr[location] == location+48 ) return true;
    else return false;
    
}

bool Game::is_victory() const
{
 if(pntr[0] == pntr[1] == pntr[2]) return true;
 if(pntr[3] == pntr[4] == pntr[5]) return true;
 if(pntr[6] == pntr[7] == pntr[8]) return true;
 if(pntr[0] == pntr[3] == pntr[6]) return true;
 if(pntr[1] == pntr[4] == pntr[7]) return true;
 if(pntr[2] == pntr[5] == pntr[8]) return true;
 if(pntr[0] == pntr[4] == pntr[8]) return true;
 if(pntr[2] == pntr[4] == pntr[6]) return true;

 return false;
}
```

Main program :

```
//tic_tac_toe_try1.cpp
#include"tic_tac_toe.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char player1;
    char player2;

    Game gameobj;

    cout<<"choose between X or O"<<endl;
    cin>> player1;

    if(player1 == 'X') player2='O';
    else player2 = 'X';
    
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        int location;

        gameobj.print();
        cout<<"enter location to enter "<< player1<<"between 0-8 as shown above : ";
        cin>> location;

        while(! (location>=0 && location<9) )
        {
            cout<<"invalid location ,  please renter location between 0-8: ";
            cin>>location;
        }

        while(!gameobj.is_empty(location) )
        {
           cout<<"invalid location , already filled please renter : ";
           cin>>location;
        }
        gameobj.insert(location, player1);
        gameobj.print();

        if(gameobj.is_victory()) 
        {
            cout<<"congrats player1 victorious";
            return 0;
        }

        

        cout<<"enter location to enter "<< player2<<"between 0-8 as shown above : ";
        cin>> location;

        while(! (location>=0 && location<9) )
        {
            cout<<"invalid location ,  please renter location between 0-8: ";
            cin>>location;
        }

        while(!gameobj.is_empty(location) )
        {
           cout<<"invalid location , already filled please renter : ";
           cin>>location;
        }
        gameobj.insert(location, player2);
        
           
        if(gameobj.is_victory()) 
        {
            cout<<"congrats player2 victorious";
            return 0;
        }
        
      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample trial in terminal of vsc :

```
PS D:\c++> g++ tic_tac_toe.cpp tic_tac_toe_try1.cpp
PS D:\c++> ./a.exe
choose between X or O
X
0|1|2|
3|4|5|
6|7|8|
enter location to enter Xbetween 0-8 as shown above : 0
X|1|2|
3|4|5|
6|7|8|
enter location to enter Obetween 0-8 as shown above : 3
X|1|2|
O|4|5|
6|7|8|
enter location to enter Xbetween 0-8 as shown above : 2
X|1|X|
O|4|5|
6|7|8|
enter location to enter Obetween 0-8 as shown above : 4
X|1|X|
O|O|5|
6|7|8|
enter location to enter Xbetween 0-8 as shown above : 1
X|X|X|
O|O|5|
6|7|8|
enter location to enter Obetween 0-8 as shown above :
```

As above even after getting 3 X's in 0,1,2 `pntr`'s `is_victory` still doesn't give true.

I also tried checking the values of `pntr[0]`, `pntr[1]`, `pntr[2]` by manually printing them and the value of expression (`pntr[0] == pntr[1] == pntr[2]`) while the earlier all print X, but the comparison results in `0`.

Comment: `x==y==z` is not the same as `x==y && x==z`

Comment: since you have found the location of the error, you can dramatically reduce the amount of code required to reproduce the error. This often removes enough noise from the problem for you to solve it yourself, and when it doesn't it presents a thoughtful example that other Stack Overflow users can easily understand and learn from or, more to your immediate needs, quickly answer. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: FYI, prefer to use ASCII character literals instead of their decimal value.  For example use `'1'` instead of `(48 + 1)`.  The former is more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(pntr[0] == pntr[1] == pntr[2]) return true;
```

The condition `A == B == C` will be evaluated as `(A == B) == C`. The expression `(A == B)` will result in *false* (`0`) or *true* (`1`), and from the initialization of `pntr` we can see that `C` will never be equal to `0` nor `1`. Therefore, the expression as a whole always evaluates to *false*.

What you probably meant to do is, e.g., this:

```
if(pntr[0] == pntr[1] && pntr[1] == pntr[2]) return true;
```